# Android SDK - List bluetooth profiles

Tags: android, testing, bluetooth, hid, profiles

In Android, is there any way to list the bluetooth profiles or even consult them by coding or at least in terminal emulator ?

I want that because most of the manufactures does not know or do not specify wich profiles are supported and I want to know (without testing) for a lot of different devices, if they can connect with HID profiles. And even if the manufacture claims support, the user can install custom ROMs that don't or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

If its a phone and supports bluez, you can check with "sdptool browse local"

Comment: That did not help, it does not show the HID profile even in a HID-capable phone.

Answer (score 1):

Not aware of anything in code that can get the list of supported profile, 
But if it is a Bluetooth device then it needs to have be Qualified and the Qualification information in https://www.bluetooth.org/tpg/listings.cfm should show the device and list the profiles it supports.
if a user modifies the ROM or anything like that then it cannot be called Bluetooth (since it voilates the Qualification sanctity)

Comment: That helps a lot, but it is not fully clear.
Cus a device could have the hardware support but do not have the software support, that's the big deal.
So, I can only be sure of devices that do not support HID if the bluetooth website said it. The positive support for any profile can not be guaranteed.

Comment: you can get information on hardware and software support from the qualified listing, BTW profile is all software if the Profile support indicates HID then it means HID is supported.